# How do I remove IP from sorbs.net blacklist?

Tags: spam, rbl

Our email server has ended up in the sorbs.net blacklist and we're going round in circles trying to get it removed, currently this is causing down-time between our suppliers.

I am a developer and not familiar with Sorbs but asked if I could take a look at it.

**UPDATE**: Our admins have determined that sorbs have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would seem that SORBS is having a database problem right now, and is blocking a lot more than it usually does. This may be a transient issue:

http://isc.sans.edu/diary.html?storyid=9685

Answer (score 16):

sorbs.net is not run by an idiot but a clever major size mafia that is there to extract money from any responsible business on the net.

It is impossible to reach them. It is impossible to login the system. It is impossible to reach any one about them. This is an outright mafia and on top very evil one

I am thinking to report it to federal govt's various agencies to look into this matter to stop them and get them arrested and hopefully a major law suite from legit users will follow.

Comment: I know this comment comes many years later, but perhaps this link would help: http://www.sorbs.net/cgi-bin/support

Comment: The support request is just a robot that tells you it can't remove your IP even if it was listed 8 years ago when it was not assigned to you.

Answer (score 4):

I've litrally just 10 seconds ago came away from there wondering how to delist myself. I have 2 IP's both "listed", one of which isnt even a mail server, delisting seemed overly complicated and required jumping through hoops, so i came to the conclusion they were a bunch of inept scammers, and gave up.

edit: Im going to put my neck on the block and put this how it needs to be said: SORBS is a scam outfit.

From some quick research there's tons of complaints about them, it appears theyve been taken to court several times, and the only way to get delisted is to pay either a charity (which people report wont actually get you delisted) or contribute towards some guys legal defence..... who happens to own the site.

If im wrong, someone please correct me, but this *stinks* of scam to me.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam_and_Open_Relay_Blocking_System#Spam_database_removal_procedure  specifically "In order for IP addresses that have spammed in the past to be removed from the spam database, SORBS requires what it calls a "fine" in the form of a US$50 donation to any registered charity"  -- smells fishy to me !

Answer (score 4):

Our server is also on the list as of the past day.

My research also points to sorbs.net being a site run by scammers or idiots. I cannot even register a user account there to research the blacklist. It times out. Maybe their server is being overwhelmed with others who are affected.

You can tell that sorbs.net is a scam in that they do not use a publicly registered certificate. You have to accept their self-signed certificate to access their HTTPS pages. If a service is truly interested in promoting legitimate mail servers, why isn't it interested in publicly registering their own site certificate?

Comment: Situation as of today: "The certificate expired on 26.07.2016 20:49. The current time is 24.02.2017 17:53." :D

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at their [de-listing page](http://www.sorbs.net/overview.shtml)? There's a big black "De-List an IP Address" button there. I'd guess that in order to get de-listed, they'll run a test again to verify that you're not exhibiting the same behavior that got you listed in the first place.

Comment: What seems to be happening is we keep going round in circles on the page with a login then an error, login, then timeout, login.. we're going nuts. It turns out that the admin finally using this method finally got to a point where he could enter the IP address and found it's an IP range and is currently talking with Telstra to try and resolve the issue.

Comment: 8 years later: yes there is a button, but that does not mean it works. Their confirmation email was detected by gmail as spam! The listing currently says my ip was sending spam 1 year ago. Strange... Why are mail-servers checking this blacklist? Apparently at least some people believe this blacklist works well

Comment: The support request is just a robot that tells you it can't remove your IP even if it was listed 8 years ago when it was not assigned to you. I've tried several times and the solution was to ask our ISP to give us another IP for our mail server.